# how can i show PDF file as Bytes using QWebEngineView in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

i need to import file from the database as Bytes and show it on the window using QWebEngineView in PyQt5.

this is my code:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
import sys


application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

PDF = "D:\export.pdf"

file = open(PDF,"rb")

PDF_as_bytes = file.read()

engine = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
engine.setMinimumSize(500,500)
engine_settings = engine.settings()
engine_settings.setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
engine_settings.setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.ShowScrollBars, True)
engine_settings.setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PdfViewerEnabled, True)
engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput(PDF))


window_layout.addWidget(engine)
window.setLayout(window_layout)
window.show()
application.exec()
```

i can show the pdf file when i put its path using this code:

```py
engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput(PDF))
```

but i need to show it from bytes data.

i tried to use this code:

```py
engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromEncoded(PDF_as_bytes))
```

but this code is wrong.

is there a way to show it using the file bytes code ?

Comment: It's a url class, not a pdf class. Have you tried entering it as a "file://" url? Try dragging the pdf into your browser to see what it labels the url as. This might help, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866298/qwebengineview-update-with-pdf-path

Comment: Maybe you could try with [`setContent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setContent).

Comment: i tried setContent and it works for text files , and when i change the MIME type to application/pdf it does not work and it shows nothing

Comment: It works fine for me on Linux using `engine.setContent(PDF_as_bytes, 'application/pdf')`, but only with relatively small files. This is because `setContent` uses a data-url which is limited to 2Mb (and may be even less than that, in practice). One work-around is to use a custom url-scheme handler (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48926971/984421)).